# Handeling fused location updates with pendingIntent

Tags: android, location, fusedlocationproviderapi

I am developing an android application in which I using fused API location updates with pending intent. Here is what I have achieved till now. I am able to listen to location updates for application in foreground and background state.I am able to stop location updates from foreground state and also resume app from background to foreground. But in the case of app restart state, I am not able to stop location updates cause once I kill the application from background then it is losing `GoogleApiClient` object and I am not able to remove updates. I tried it in following way :

```
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_location);

    updateStatusForLocationListening();
    initUi();
    // if condition to check whether already started listening for updates.
    if (!isLocationUpdatesOn) {
        initLocationListeningProcess();
    }
    registerLocationListener();
}

private void initLocationListeningProcess() {

    createLocationPendingIntent();
    initLocationListener();

    createLocationRequest();
    buildLocationSettingsRequest();
    checkForLocationPermission();
}

private void createLocationPendingIntent() {
    Intent intervalIntent = new Intent(this, LocationPendingIntentService.class);
    locationPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 1, intervalIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
}

private void initLocationListener() {
    buildGoogleApiClient();
}
synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
        .addApi(LocationServices.API)
        .build();


}

private void createLocationRequest() {
    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(100); // Update location every second
}
protected void buildLocationSettingsRequest() {
    LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder();
    builder.addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);
    mLocationSettingsRequest = builder.build();
}
protected void checkLocationSettings() {
    PendingResult < LocationSettingsResult > result =
        LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(
            mGoogleApiClient,
            mLocationSettingsRequest
        );
    result.setResultCallback(this);
}

private void processStopLocation() {
    // user clicks on stop button.
    // Here it is loosing mGoogleApiClient if user kills the application from the background. It keeps listening for updates.
    // But when try to stop it, its giving Null pointer exception.
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, locationPendingIntent);

    unregisterLocationListener();
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
}
private void processStartLocation() {
    // user click on start button.
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, locationPendingIntent);

        mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        if (mLastLocation != null) {
            updateUI();
        }
    }
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
public class LocationPendingIntentService extends IntentService {

    public LocationPendingIntentService(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    public LocationPendingIntentService() {
        super("");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Location location = intent.getParcelableExtra(FusedLocationProviderApi.KEY_LOCATION_CHANGED);
        if (location != null) {
            Log.i("***********", "Lcation Received ");
            Intent locationIntent = new Intent("LOCATION_UPDATES_AVAILABLE");
            locationIntent.putExtra("location", location);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(locationIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

So in my case, I killed the application from the background and again start it. It showing location updates. I try to stop it. It gives me the null pointer for `mGoogleApiClient` object. I try to create the new object for `GoogleApiClient`. But once I create the new object then it stops previously started location updates. That mean I need to start new location updates. Is there any way to store this object or get the current live object of `mGoogleApiClient`. So that I can stop it. Is there any wrong implementation I am following or something else I am missing? Need some help. Thank you.

Comment: Disconnect the older one `mGoogleApiClient` and create new connection may be the solution.

Comment: When you called processStopLocation ?

Comment: Thank you for quick replay. I can call stop updates anytime. One I done with location updates I can call stop location updates. Is Disconnecting starting it once again good solution or there is some else as well?

Comment: If you want to get Location continuously then implement `Service` with `googleApiClient` and `broadCast` that `Location` in `Activity`. It's better to handle in different class.

Comment: Ok mean put all those location related stuff into service. Then just start and stop service when needed.

Comment: exactly when ever you don't want any location just Stop that service. Service will automatically destroy and you can stop Location updates over there

Comment: Ok will try this solution. Also please let me know solution for above problem. Thank you for good idea.